# HttpClient = INVALID URI - Escaped absolute path not valid

Tags: java, url, absolute-path, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to upload/delete a file to webdav server using HttpClient. However, none is working whenever I have a file name consist of space . I got a error message saying "INVALID URI--- Escaped absolute path not valid".

this my URL = "http://localhost:8080/test file.txt"

```
private boolean delete(String fileName) {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpHost host = new HttpHost(WEBDAV_URL, PORT_NUMBER);
    client.getHostConfiguration().setHost(host);
    DeleteMethod del = new DeleteMethod(WEBDAV_URL_COMPLETE + fileName);
    try {
        client.executeMethod(del);
        return true;
    } catch (HttpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

is there any method or URL parse should I use to fix the problem

thanks

EDIT, FOUND the solution by replace space with "**%20**".

**

> URL.replaceAll(" ","%20")

**

Comment: I had the same problem. But the URL contained a "-", in this case I needed to replace by %2D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used this and get what I want...

URL.replaceAll(" ","%20")

Answer (score 2):

use `java.net.URLEncoder.encode`

or replace your spaces with '+'

Comment: `+` is only acceptable in query strings and application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST data. Real encoding uses `%20` here.

Comment: Thanks @Neil, I just update my question with the solution. %20 work great on the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply rename your file as:

```
test_file.txt or textFile.txt
```

It is common standard to never use spaces when coding variables or creating files for such.

Use test_file (snake case) or textFile (camelCase).